# Unable to successfully navigate using Dart code in a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

In my flutter project, I am utilizing `HTML/JS/CSS` for a CDN I want to use. Inside the HTML file I am attempting to add a simple "Exit" button that will bring the user back to the home screen.

On clicking the button, I am consistently hitting the `console.error` in the `javascript` code.

Any help would be appreciated!

**editor.html:**

```
document.getElementById('exitEditorButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (typeof window.exitEditorFromWidget === "function") {
          window.exitEditorFromWidget();
        } else {
          console.error("Exit function not found.");
        }
      });
```

**editor_widget.dart:**

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    js.context['exitEditorFromWidget'] = exitEditor;

  }


  void exitEditor() {
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
      )); 
}
```